# Writing data to text file in Node.js

Tags: node.js, file-io

Currently, I have the following block of code:

```
net = require('net');
var clients = [];

net.createServer(function(s) {

  clients.push(s);

  s.on('data', function (data) {
    clients.forEach(function(c) {
      c.write(data);
    });
    process.stdout.write(data);//write data to command window
  });

  s.on('end', function() {
    process.stdout.write("lost connection");
  });

}).listen(9876);
```

Which is used to set up my Windows computer as a server and receive data from my linux computer.  It is currently writing data to the command window.  I would like to write the data into a text file to specific location, how do i do this?

Comment: Note that Java is not the same as JavaScript; Node.js is server-side *JavaScript*.

Comment: thats why i said in newbie on this, i know nth abt java :(

Comment: Fortunately the language you are working in is JavaScript, you don't need to know anything about Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`fs`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_filename_data_options_callback) module to deal with the filesystem:

```
var net = require('net');
var fs = require('fs');
// ...snip
s.on('data', function (data) {
  clients.forEach(function(c) {
    c.write(data);
  });

  fs.writeFile('myFile.txt', data, function(err) {
    // Deal with possible error here.
  });
});
```

Comment: By default, writeFile() will overwrite anything that was already in the file, so this answer will only leave the last 'data' item in the file.

Comment: well, this exactly wt i want to do, over write the data, and leave the latest data in the text file only.

Comment: However, the problem I am having at the moment is, I dont have any error, but i cant file the .txt file even with the search function of windows :/

Comment: @FWing The txt file should be in the directory where you ran `node`

Comment: oh alrite, thank you, i got it, not sure why the search function doesnt work

Answer (score 4):

You should read up on the [File System](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system) support in node.js.

The following method is probably the simplest way to do what you want, but it is not necessarily the most efficient, since it creates/opens, updates, and then closes the file every time.

```
function myWrite(data) {
    fs.appendFile('output.txt', data, function (err) {
      if (err) { /* Do whatever is appropriate if append fails*/ }
    });
}
```

Comment: is it a must that i hv to be prepare when i encounter an error? i have no idea wt to do?

Comment: You could just output an error to the console, if you don't know what else to do. For example: console.error("Failed to output data. Data: %s, Error:  %s", data, err);

Comment: same problem here, i dont hv any error, but i couldnt find my file, im not sure if the code is working

Comment: You can explicitly specify the full path for the file, so that you know where it goes.

Comment: yes, i made it, thank you very much!

Comment: The default directory is the directory that holds your node.js code.